# CSS3 select each first item of specified classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following situation:

```
<ul>
  <li class="a">...</li>
  <li class="a">...</li>
  <li class="a">...</li>   
  ...
  <li class="b">...</li>
  <li class="b">...</li>
  ...
  <li class="c">...</li>
  <li class="c">...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Et cetera for each letter; Now I'd want to add a pseudoelement before the first element that begins with each letter, something like:

```
<ul>
 A
 <li class="a">...</li>
  <li class="a">...</li>
  <li class="a">...</li>   
  ...
  B
  <li class="b">...</li>
  <li class="b">...</li>
  ...
  C
  <li class="c">...</li>
  <li class="c">...</li>
  ...
</ul>
```

Note: the classes are always in the alphabetical order, i.e. `a a a a b b b b b c c c ...`; and never mixed e.g. `a a a b b a c c b a b a a`

Would it be possible using only CSS3 rules? Thank you for your answer!

Comment: You can use `:first-of-type` selector. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type

Comment: pseudo element can only be added inside the element and before its content not before the element

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, like this: add for each letter:

```
.a:before{
  content:"a";
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.a + .a:before{
  content:none;
}
.b:before{
  content:"b";
  display:block;
  border-bottom:1px solid #000;
}
.b + .b:before{
  content:none;
}
...
```

I am wondering if there is a more clever solution...

**[EDIT]**

Following the example by @Satif this is an alternative solution:

```
.ln-a:first-child:before{
  content:"A";
  display: block;
}

.ln-b:first-child, :not(.ln-b) + .ln-b:before {
  content:"B";
  display: block;
}


.ln-c:first-child, :not(.ln-c) + .ln-c:before {
  content:"C";
  display: block;
}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

But need to think about list middle dot

```
.a:first-child, :not(.a) + .a {
  color: red;
}

.a:first-child:before, :not(.a) + .a {
  content: 'A';
  display: block;
}


.b:first-child, :not(.b) + .b {
  color: blue;
}

.c:first-child, :not(.c) + .c {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I added to the question a note to make my goal more clear.